# Destructure object properties inside Array.prototype.map()

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am using Next.js and mapping out some components with the below code. All works as it should but I would really like to destrcuture the object properties here to not be repeating the paths inside my props

```
 {sortedData.map((service) => (
          <Article
            key={uuidv4()}
            title={service.fields.title}
            image={service.fields.thumbnail.fields.file.url}
            alt={service.fields.thumbnail.fields.file.fileName}
            slug={service.fields.slug}
            content={service.fields.intro}
            height={service.fields.thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.height}
            width={service.fields.thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.width}
          />
        ))}
```

I tried looking for similar questions here but could not find any. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `.map(({ fields: { title, ... } }) =>`?

Comment: If you don't know how to do destructuring, use the standard approach and introduce temporary variables: `service => { const fields = service.fields; const thumbFile = fields.thumbnail.fields.file; return …; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desestructure service object, example:

```
   {sortedData.map(({ fields: { title, thumbnail, slug, intro } }) => (
      <Article
        key={uuidv4()}
        title={title}
        image={thumbnail.fields.file.url}
        alt={thumbnail.fields.file.fileName}
        slug={slug}
        content={intro}
        height={thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.height}
        width={thumbnail.fields.file.details.image.width}
      />
    ))}
```